# PHP JSON output with mysql for tag-it

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, tag-it

I'm trying to get the tag-it jquery plugin to work with a json string. 
Currenttly i'm getting my values from the database like this:

```
$query = sprintf(
            'SELECT
                t.tag
            FROM
                tags AS t
            ');

    $row_set= array();

    if($result = mysqli_query($db, $query))
    {
        // fetch data
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $row_set[] = $row;
        }

        // set the output
        echo json_encode($row_set);
    }
```

which gives the following output when called in AJAX:

```
[{"tag":"test"},{"tag":"tests"}]
```

But I have to output a JSON string in the following format:

```
["android-intent","animate","architecture","artificial-intelligence","attributes"]
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `row_set[] = $row;` most likely `$row` looks like this `$row['tag'] = 'test`  that is why you are having JSON  object format;

Try

```
  $row_set[] = $row['tag'];
```

Make sure you also set the seound parameter to `true` to make `JSON` always return array

```
   json_encode($row_set,true);
```

This would return the it as array not as a object

Comment: this gives me the correct output, but the tag-it gives all charachter as suggestions in auto-complete
it gives [ " t e s t as seperate 'tags'...
edit: nevermind! forgot the dataType: "json",

Answer (score 2):

That should fix it, by adding string into you arrow instead of adding arrays into you array.

```
$row_set[] = $row[0]; or $row_set[] = $row['tag'];
```